# How to run Mathematica source code in Linux command line when some external file need to be imported and the result need to export?

Tags: coding-style, command-line, scripting

I want to run a short code like that in the linux command line

```
(*Set the work directory*)    
SetDirectory["/data0/PredinctModleFingerprint/Predict/CXT/20170703"];
(*Import the data source*)
testdata = Import["test.csv"] // Flatten;
plot = ListPlot[testdata];
Export["myplot.png", plot]
```

the `test.csv` is a `csv` file which is in the same directory with the script. the file just contain some numbers as follow.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

now I want to import the file, and export the list plot named as myplot.png.
The code runs good in the Mathematica front-end Notebook on the windows platform . But I need to run this code in  remote commands line. So I save this code from `test.nb` to `test.m`, and run the code as follow on the linux platform

```
MathematicaScript -script test.m
```

and

```
MathKernel -noprompt -initfile test.m
```

and

```
math -noprompt -script test.m
```

I get nothing.

then I save the .nb file as wolfram language package, and run

```
wolfram -script test.wl
```

but I still get noting.

Comment: Your procedure works ok, but you have to `SetDirectory` to something else then `NotebookDirectory[]` (e.g. explicit directory name) because you are not using a notebook.

Comment: @Pinti Thank you. I changed the work directory, and tried the four command line. but I do not get the output file `myplot.png`

Comment: Try the front end function been a while since I tried this but might work.

Comment: @William Thank you, could you explain in more detail

Comment: @ZihuGuo try evaluating your code in `FrontEndExecute[code]` or maybe `UsingFrontEnd` that is all I can recall.